# Find all solutions $10^x=11^y-1$

Tags: number-theory

I tried to solve this like this.

$x=1,y=1$ is solution.

And Let $x=a y=b\, (a\geq 1,b\geq2)$

Then, $11$ can divide $11^b = 10^a+1$

so $10^a = 10 \pmod{11}$ but order of $11(10) = 2$.

Then there is contradiction.

Can I solve this problem while I make $x=a y=b\, (a\geq2 , b\geq1)$?

Comment: Presumably, you are looking for positive integer solutions?

Comment: You probably can but I doubt that's the most efficient way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's calculate evaluation of $5$ for RHS, we have$$x=v_5(11^y-1)=v_5(y)+v_5(11-1)=v_5(y)+1$$which gives $v_5(y)=x-1$ and we can write $y=5^{x-1}z$, where $\gcd(z, 5)=1$ is a positive integer, but for $x>1$ $$11^{5^{x-1}z}-1>11^{x}-1>10^x$$which is a contradiction. Hence $x=1$, which leads to $y=1$.

Answer (score 1):

If you take logarithms in both sides you get $x=log(11^y-1)$ so you have a solution for each $y$ greater than $0$. This works in case you aren´t looking for integer solutions.

Comment: Dear Michael: When evaluated in $g$ the sequence you propose gives the cero sequence so here we are again, this sequence does not work if you are to apply the definition of limit to the composition $h\circ g$, because you are trying to claculate the limit of $h$ in $x=0$ using a cero sequence!!!